# Github copilot activation woes in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, github-copilot

I got Copilot to work immediately in Visual Studio Code but on the same laptop can't get it working in Visual Studio 2022. I installed the extension and when I restart VS22 and load a project I get the messagebox from Copilot to connect with the activation code procedure. Clicking OK however results in the following in the output window (pressed the button a seconde time when the messagebox appeared again):

> GitHub Copilot 1.84.0.1 (v1.84.0.1@760da3695) [DEBUG] [agent]
> [2023-06-01T17:09:44.368Z] Agent service starting [DEBUG] [agent]
> [2023-06-01T17:09:44.714Z] Telemetry initialized GitHub Copilot Agent
> v1.84.0 [Error] An error occurred for
> 'RunOperation:SignInInitiateAsync':
> StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request signInInitiate failed
> with message: self signed certificate in certificate chain    at
> StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__151`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at GitHub.Copilot.CopilotClient.<RunOperation>d__20`1.MoveNext() [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:09:52.281Z] Agent service starting [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:09:52.337Z] Telemetry initialized [Error] An
> error occurred for 'RunOperation:RunOperation':
> StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request signInInitiate failed
> with message: self signed certificate in certificate chain    at
> StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__151`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at GitHub.Copilot.CopilotClient.<RunOperation>d__20`1.MoveNext() [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:09:53.585Z] Agent service starting [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:09:53.620Z] Telemetry initialized NotSignedIn
> [Error] An error occurred for 'RunOperation:SignInInitiateAsync':
> StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request signInInitiate failed
> with message: self signed certificate in certificate chain    at
> StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__151`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at GitHub.Copilot.CopilotClient.<RunOperation>d__20`1.MoveNext() [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:10:08.313Z] Agent service starting [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:10:08.346Z] Telemetry initialized [Error] An
> error occurred for 'RunOperation:RunOperation':
> StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Request signInInitiate failed
> with message: self signed certificate in certificate chain    at
> StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__151`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at GitHub.Copilot.CopilotClient.<RunOperation>d__20`1.MoveNext() [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:10:08.957Z] Agent service starting [DEBUG]
> [agent] [2023-06-01T17:10:08.971Z] Telemetry initialized NotSignedIn

I've been searching around and tried already to flip Options > Github Copilot > Accept non-trusted certificate authorization to True. However still without being the solution.

Anyone facing this and, hopefully, has a workaround which works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to follow the steps mentioned in this answer: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50484.

Basically it turned out that netskope was in between for traffic and that the certificate needed to be added on my laptop with the command:

`setx NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS "C:\temp\caadmin.netskope.com"`

after I had saved the certificate caadmin.netskope.com under c:\temp.